# Why does OpenProcess() return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED only for some processes?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

`OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, TRUE, pid)` returns successfully for, for example, an Administrator cmd.exe and non-Administrator cmd.exe. However, when I pass in the pid for a node.exe process, it fails and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Can someone tell me how to get access to this process object?

UPDATE: I believe I've done all that @ErykSun suggested in the following code. I've gotten further, but, now, `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (I stripped out all error handling to make the code easier to understand here). Moreover, now my program cannot disable privileges for lower-integrity levels, e.g., non-Administrator cmd.exe. (The two function prototypes are for helper functions following the `disable_all_privileges()` function. They are, hopefully, correct.)

```
BOOL set_privilege(HANDLE hToken, const char* privilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege);
BOOL get_self_token(HANDLE* phToken);
int disable_all_privileges(DWORD pid)
{
    int ret = 1;
    HANDLE hSelfToken;
    if (get_self_token(&hSelfToken)) {
        if (set_privilege(hSelfToken, "SeDebugPrivilege", TRUE)) {
            if (set_privilege(hSelfToken, "SeImpersonatePrivilege", TRUE)) {
                const HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
                if (hProcess) {
                    HANDLE hToken;
                    if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
                        print_privileges(hToken);
                        if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken))
                            if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, TRUE, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL) && GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                                print_privileges(hToken);
                                ret = 0;
                            }
                        CloseHandle(hToken);
                    }
                }
                set_privilege(hSelfToken, "SeImpersonatePrivilege", FALSE);
            }
            set_privilege(hSelfToken, "SeDebugPrivilege", FALSE);
        }
        CloseHandle(hSelfToken);
    }
    return ret;
}

BOOL set_privilege(HANDLE hToken, const char* privilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;
    LUID luid;
    if (LookupPrivilegeValueA(NULL, privilege, &luid)) {
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tpPrevious;
        DWORD cbPrevious = sizeof tpPrevious;
        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof tp, &tpPrevious, &cbPrevious);
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            tpPrevious.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
            if (bEnablePrivilege)
                tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes |= SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            else
                tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes ^= SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED & tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes;
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tpPrevious, cbPrevious, NULL, NULL);
            ok = GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return ok;
}

BOOL get_self_token(HANDLE* phToken)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;
    if (OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, phToken))
        ok = TRUE;
    else
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
            if (ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation))
                if (OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, phToken))
                    ok = TRUE;
    return ok;
}
```

Comment: different processes can have different *DACL* (usually inherit from parent process token). however if you have debug privilege - you can open any process, except protected

Comment: Request `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access if that's enough. However, even in this case, you'll need to enable SeDebugPrivilege if the DACL doesn't grant access.

Comment: @ErykSun, I tried that instead of what I have, but I got the same result. Are you saying that node.exe is a protected process whereas cmd.exe is not? How can I determine whether a process is protected (whatever that means)? I'll give SeDebugPrivilege a try...

Comment: not think (almost sure) that *node.exe* is protected process. you need look it dacl and compare with self token. however are you have *SeDebugPrivilege* ? if yes, you can open *node.exe*

Comment: Available access depends on the DACL, which implicitly grants the owner `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` access. Regardless of the DACL, the mandatory access control policy for process objects denies read-up access from lower integrity levels (e.g. a high integrity level security context can't read a system integrity level process), except for reading limited information with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access. SeDebugPrivilege overrides both the DACL and mandatory label, except it doesn't override protected process protection levels (e.g. PsProtectedSignerWinTcb-Light).

Comment: I enabled SeDebugPrivilege for my process. `hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid)` now succeeds. However, the subsequent, `OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKAN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)`, fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` even though SeDebugPrivilege is still enabled. I guess I need to look into this thing called "DACL."

Comment: `PROCESS_QUERY_LMITED_INFORMATION` allows accessing the token of a process in the kernel, but opening a handle to the token still requires access to be granted by entries in the token's discretionary access control list (DACL). Also, regardless of what discretionary access is granted to a user, mandatory access control for a token object denies write-up access for security contexts at a lower integrity level (e.g. medium vs. high or system level), which includes the 'adjust' rights such as `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES` and `TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS`.

Comment: In other words, if the token object is at system integrity level, but your security context is only at high integrity level (i.e. elevated admin), then you will not be able to open it directly with `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES` access. Instead, try opening with `TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE` access; ensure that SeImpersonatePrivilege is enabled in your current token and call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` on the opened token. Now, while impersonating, you should be able to call `OpenProcessToken` with the desired 'adjust' right such as `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES`.

Comment: @ErykSun, I endeavored to follow your recommendations, but, now, `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` fails. Can you review the code, above? Did I get something wrong? It's easy to confuse the current process with the process I'm trying to affect.

Comment: You missed a step. The point of these steps was to try to get write (adjust) access to a token when its DACL doesn't grant you write access or you're denied write access because you're running at a lower integrity level (e.g. the token is at system level and you're at high level). Assuming you have the right to query and duplicate the token, and you have SeImpersonatePrivilege, then open the token, impersonate it, and then *open it again* (from the impersonated security context) with the required write access. You missed the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. Here's the code for the little program that disables all of a process's privileges. The pid is passed on the command line. I wouldn't have been able to do it without Eryk Sun's help (thanks!). (See UPDATE at bottom.)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

void print_privileges(HANDLE hToken)
{
    DWORD size;
    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, NULL, 0, &size) && GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = malloc(size);
        if (tp != NULL && GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, tp, size, &size)) {
            size_t i;
            for (i = 0; i < tp->PrivilegeCount; ++i) {
                char name[64];
                DWORD NAME_SIZE = sizeof name;
                LookupPrivilegeNameA(0, &tp->Privileges[i].Luid, name, &NAME_SIZE);
                BOOL fResult;
                PRIVILEGE_SET ps = {
                    1, PRIVILEGE_SET_ALL_NECESSARY, {
                        { { tp->Privileges[i].Luid.LowPart, tp->Privileges[i].Luid.HighPart } }
                    }
                };
                PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &ps, &fResult);
                printf("%-*s %s\n", 42, name, fResult ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
            }
        }
        free(tp);
    }
}

BOOL set_privilege(HANDLE hToken, const char* privilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;

    LUID luid;
    if (LookupPrivilegeValueA(NULL, privilege, &luid)) {
        // first pass.  get current privilege setting
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tpPrevious;
        DWORD cbPrevious = sizeof tpPrevious;
        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof tp, &tpPrevious, &cbPrevious);
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            // second pass.  set privilege based on previous setting
            tpPrevious.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
            if (bEnablePrivilege)
                tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes |= SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            else
                tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes ^= SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED & tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes;
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tpPrevious, cbPrevious, NULL, NULL);
            ok = GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    return ok;
}

BOOL get_current_token(HANDLE* phToken)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;

    if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, phToken)) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
            if (ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation))
                if (OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, phToken))
                    ok = TRUE;
    } else
        ok = TRUE;

    return ok;
}

BOOL impersonate_process(HANDLE hProcess)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;

    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
        if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken))
            ok = TRUE;
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    return ok;
}

BOOL disable_all_privileges(HANDLE hProcess)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;

    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
        puts("\nBefore:");
        print_privileges(hToken);
        /* disable all privileges */
        if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, TRUE, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL))
            /* AdjustTokenPrivileges() could succeed but still not disable all privileges */
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED) {
                puts("\nAfter:");
                print_privileges(hToken);
                ok = TRUE;
            }
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    return ok;
}

BOOL reduce_privileges(DWORD pid)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;

    /* in case target process has higher integrity level than this process, e.g., system versus
     * high integrity, enable SeDebugPrivilege and impersonate target process */
    HANDLE hCurrentToken;
    if (get_current_token(&hCurrentToken)) {
        if (set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeDebugPrivilege", TRUE)) {
            if (set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeImpersonatePrivilege", TRUE)) {
                /* get process handle with only the least access needed */
                const HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
                if (hProcess) {
                    if (impersonate_process(hProcess))
                        /* now we should be able to adjust the privileges of any target process */
                        if (disable_all_privileges(hProcess))
                            ok = TRUE;
                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
                }
                /* disable privileges we no longer need */
                set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeImpersonatePrivilege", FALSE);
            }
            set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeDebugPrivilege", FALSE);
        }
        CloseHandle(hCurrentToken);
    }

    return ok;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    if (argc > 1)
        sscanf_s(argv[1], "%u", &pid);
    return pid && reduce_privileges(pid) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

UPDATE: Here is the improved `reduce_privilege()` with Eryk's further suggestions. This way, we only enable and use the impersonate privilege if absolutely necessary.

```
int reduce_privileges(DWORD pid)
{
    int ret = 1;

    HANDLE hCurrentToken;
    if (get_current_token(&hCurrentToken)) {
        const BOOL debug_set = set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeDebugPrivilege", TRUE);
        /* regardless of whether we got debug privilege, try to get process handle with the least access needed */
        const HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
        if (hProcess) {
            /* see if we can disable privileges of target process without the impersonate privilege;
               if we can't, enable that privilege, impersonate, and try again */
            if (disable_all_privileges(hProcess))
                ret = 0;
            else
                if (set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeImpersonatePrivilege", TRUE)) {
                    if (impersonate_process(hProcess))
                        /* now we should be able to adjust the privileges of any target process */
                        if (disable_all_privileges(hProcess))
                            ret = 0;
                    /* impersonate privilege no longer needed */
                    set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeImpersonatePrivilege", FALSE);
                }
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
        /* debug privilege no longer needed */
        if (debug_set)
            set_privilege(hCurrentToken, "SeDebugPrivilege", FALSE);
        CloseHandle(hCurrentToken);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: For the comment in `reduce_privileges`, the approach used there requires an elevated logon in order to use the super privileges, SeDebugPrivilege and SeImpersonatePrivilege, so the current security context is already at high integrity level. Impersonating allows getting write (adjust) access if the token is at system level or if the token's DACL doesn't grant write access to administrators. A standard user isn't privileged to do this.

Comment: I would first try to enable SeDebugPrivilege, and regardless of whether that succeeds, try `disable_all_privileges`. If it fails, try to enable SeImpersonatePrivilege. If the privilege is present and enabled (i.e. check `GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS` after calling `AdjustTokenPrivileges`), then impersonate the token from the target process and retry `disable_all_privileges`. If the privilege is not present (i.e. `GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`), then don't bother because you'll only be able to impersonate at identification level, which isn't useful here.

Comment: Thanks again, Eryk. I included a version of the new `reduce_privileges()` as an UPDATE to my "Answer," above. Looks like I'll always need impersonation for node.exe, but this makes the code more general purpose and only grabs that privilege if necessary.